# Ensure that listbox and collection both start at same point (0 or 1)

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code in a button click event:

```
    If myCollection.Count > 0 Then
        Dim curItemIndex As Integer = myListbox.SelectedIndex
        If myCollection.Item(curItemIndex) IsNot Nothing Then
            myCollection.Remove(curItemIndex)
            MessageBox.Show("Address removed!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Could not delete entry!")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Address book is empty!")
    End If
```

When I add an item to the collection, then try to remove it, I always get this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Collection index must be in the
>   range 1 to the size of the collection.'

When I step through the debugger, I see this:

- myCollection.Count = 1
- SelectedIndex = 0
- curItemIndex = 0

So I don't get why the currently selected item in the listbox is 0 when it says the collection starts at 1.

How can I fix this so that both start at 0?

Thanks!

Comment: If you continue using `Collection`, then `If myCollection.Item(curItemIndex+1) IsNot Nothing Then` `myCollection.Remove(curItemIndex+1)`. But you should use a `List`, and bind the ListView to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a VB collection which is one based. Explore the System.Collections.Generic Namespace as Microsoft recommends. One of the simplest classes is List (Of T) if your collection is all the same datatype. Then your listbox index and your List index should match (both zero based). To keep them in sync be sure to remove the item from the listbox too.